# Interpolating a line between two other lines in python

Tags: python, math, geometry, line, interpolation

Does anyone know of a python library that can interpolate between two lines. For example, given the two solid lines below, I would like to produce the dashed line in the middle. In other words, I'd like to get the centreline. The input is a just two `numpy` arrays of coordinates with size `N x 2` and `M x 2` respectively.

[image]

**Edit**: so the suggested duplicate seems to be a promising way to approach this. However, it assumes that there is an outer and inner curve with respect to a single origin (0,0). I believe this algorithm would fail in examples such as the one below:

[image]

Furthermore, I'd like to know if someone has written a function for this in some optimized python library. Although optimization isn't exactly a necessary.

Comment: You can triangulate the zone between the curves and join the midpoints of the zigzagging edges. (Unfortunately, I cannot post a figure as the question was - IMO unduely - closed.)

Comment: "The input is a just a numpy array of coordinates with size N x 2." <- You mean that's the input for just one of the lines? So you have _two_ NumPy arrays of shape `(N, 2)`? Do they both have the same `N`?

Comment: Dang, should I repost this question...? And yeah there are two NumPy arrays sorry. I should mention that they are different in size, so one is `(N, 2)` and the other is `(M, 2)`.